# How can I remove spaces from this PowerShell array?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get all ASCII numbers and letters from Powershell for use as a key later on.

My code so far looks like this:

```
[char[]] $keyArray = @()
for($i = 65;$i -le 122;$i++) 
{
    if($i -lt 91 -or $i -gt 96)  
    {
        $keyArray += [char]$i
    }  
}
for($i = 0; $i -le 9; $i++)
{
    $keyArray += ("$i")
}

Write-Host [string]$keyArray
```

However, when I write this out (last line), I get the following with spaces in between each character:

`A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

How can I remove those spaces?

Comment: `-join(@('A'[0]..'Z'[0];'a'[0]..'z'[0];'0'[0]..'9'[0])|%{[char]$_})` But really use `StringBuilder` instead of that `[char[]] $keyArray = @()`. I does not really want to think about what happens when you then do `$keyArray += ...`.

Comment: Wow. Now I feel stupid. Much simpler thank you. Do you want to add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-join` operator to join array elements. Binary form of that operator allows you to specify custom separator:

```
-join $keyArray
$keyArray -join $separator
```

If you really have array of characters, then you can just call `String` constructor:

```
New-Object String (,$keyArray)
[String]::new($keyArray) #PS v5
```

And does not use array addition. It slow and unnecessary. Array operator `@()` is powerful enough in most cases:

```
$keyArray = [char[]] @(
    for($i = 65;$i -le 122;$i++)
    {
        if($i -lt 91 -or $i -gt 96)
        {
            $i
        }
    }
    for($i = 0; $i -le 9; $i++)
    {
        "$i"
    }
)
```

With use of PowerShell range operator you code can be simplified:

```
$keyArray = [char[]] @(
    'A'[0]..'Z'[0]
    'a'[0]..'z'[0]
    '0'[0]..'9'[0]
)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want one character per line:

```
Write-Host ($keyArray | out-string)
```

If you want all chars on one line:

```
Write-Host ($keyArray -join '')
```

Comment: I was doing like this :
$array=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

for ($i=0; $i -le 6; $i++)
{
    if ($args[$i])
    {
    $array.add("`t"+$args[$i])
    }
    else
    {
    $array.add("`t"+0)
    }
}
But it was adding a space before the tab. and I added below as you answered :
$array=$array -join ''
That did work !!!!!
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Use the builtin Output Field Seperator as follows (one-line, use semi-colon to separate, and you MUST cast `$keyArray` to `[string]` for this to work):

```
$OFS = '';[string]$keyArray
```

[Reference](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/effective-powershell-item-15-using-the-output-field-separator-ofs/)